# Trying to play a mp3 file when a page reloads in jsp using the <object> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have used the following code to play a sound:

```
<object>
<param name="autostart" value="true">
<param name="src" value="bgmusic.mp3">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="controller" value="true">

<embed id="hidden-embed" src="bgmusic.mp3" controller="true" volume="1" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/mpeg" hidden="true" loop="true" />
</object>
```

The mp3 is being played in a notmal html page. However when putting the same tags in a jsp page its not being played. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: When you view source in browser is this making it to the source?

Comment: Open your browser's debug tools, check if the `bgmusic.mp3` can be found and if there are any errors in the console.